# Fatal error: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri::composeComponents() in CodeIgneter

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, codeigniter, amazon-s3, guzzle

Can anyone help me, I have the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp \ Psr7 \ Uri ::
>   composeComponents ()

Can anyone help fix it? Thank you, and this is my script :

```
use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

//JWT
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

\Firebase\JWT\JWT::$leeway = 10;
```

And This is my upload file script :

```
$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'region'      => 'ap-southeast-1',
    'credentials' => 'my-credentials'
]);

$handle = fopen($uploadPath.$filename, 'r');
try {
    $result = $s3->putObject([
        'Bucket' => 'my-bucket',    
        'Key'    => 'Campaign/'.$filename,

        //Upload File
        'Body'   => $handle,
        'ACL'    => 'public-read',
        'params' => array('ContentType' => $_FILES['resourceFile']['type'])
    ]);

    // New URL
    $fileURL = $result['ObjectURL'];
    fclose($handle);
    unlink($target);
} catch (Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e."\nThere was an error uploading the file.\n";
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. I would highly suggest that you edit your question following the guidelines of [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As StackOverflow is not meant to be used as a forum to help you debug your code. You may also want to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get more familiar with SO and what is expected.

Comment: Post your entire code. You are missing the top section that defines the AWS SDK.

Comment: Okey, like this ?